# Create an array of files to add in zip?

Tags: php, zip

How do I add a list of files to an array and then add that array to a zip? I am using php in order to achieve this. I am able to add a single file without an array but adding an array is causing an issue.

```
<?
...
...

$file = array();
$file[] = "001.pdf";
$file[] = "002.pdf";

$length = count($file);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$tmp_file = 'Documents.zip';
    if($zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE|ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
        for($i=0;$i < $length ;$i=$i+1) //Here is where i read the array
       {
        $zip->addFile($file, "$i.pdf"); //Here is the problem
        }
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Archive created!';
         header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Documents.zip');
         header('Content-type: application/zip');

   } else {
       echo 'Failed!';
   }
   ob_end_clean(); 
   readfile($tmp_file);

?>
```

Comment: The problematic line should be replaced with: `$zip->addFile($file[$i], "$i.pdf");`

Comment: @user1165759 yes i totally forgot to add the array there.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
All i had to loop was foreach item instead of for loop.

```
 foreach($file as $files) {
            $zip->addFile($files,$files);
        }
```